# jQuery injecting video element with new source

Tags: jquery, video

I'm trying to replace webm formated video with another one each time I click on corresponding link, using Chrome (I only have webm media resource).

I succeed in placing the new source in src attribute, following with load() and play() method, but video won't start. When I place the same url in src manually, works well.

This is a part of the HTML:

```
<figure>
<video id="frag" autoplay controls>
<source src="" type="video/webm">
</video>
</figure>
<p>
<a href="#article3" class="game" rel="http://ninsuna.elis.ugent.be/Media/Showcase/Tennis/2009_FROpen_F_Federer-Soderling.webm?t=0.0,270.72">Game 1</a>
</p>
<p>
<a href="#article3" class="game" rel="http://ninsuna.elis.ugent.be/Media/Showcase/Tennis/2009_FROpen_F_Federer-Soderling.webm?t=317.04,379.88">Game 2</a>
</p>
...
```

and the script:

```
setTimeout(function() {
$(".game").click(function() {
var videoUrl = $(this).attr("rel");
$('#frag source').attr('src', videoUrl);
$('#frag').load();
$('#frag').play();
});
}, 1000);
```

(for some reason I have to use timeout, document load doesn't work, for the link list is dynamically generated)

You can check it here more thoughrouly: [link to my web](http://b-webdesign.com/multilab/Ver2.3/#article3)

Answer (score 2):

You are calling a `play` method on a `jQuery` object which will not work. You should either use `get` or `[0]` to get the `HTMLVideo` element and then call play method on it. Same applies to `load` method as well. Try this

```
$(function() {
  $(".game").click(function() {
     var videoUrl = $(this).attr("rel");
     $('#frag source').attr('src', videoUrl);
     $('#frag')[0].load();
     $('#frag')[0].play();
  });
});
```

Comment: makes sense, but still not working with '[0]' there :/ same thing if I try to 'get' it

Comment: Tried, but now it won't even place the new sources into video. I'm fetching these urls from external json and placing them into links rel attribute with jquery.

Comment: Where are you loading the jQuery js file?

Comment: I just replaced the whole HTML code inside video element, it works, I will leave this source method to remain a mistery :) P.S. jQuery file is loading below the html code of the video

Comment: Thats were the problem is. You should at least include the jQuery file at the begining of the page. Then it will work.

Comment: jQuery library? I put that in header, I thought you were referring to the jQuery method I wrote :)

Comment: Nah, I'm just replacing the whole source tag. Injecting src attribute is for some reason simply not working..